# select data when id is letters - not numbers

Tags: php, mysql

How can i use letters instead of numbers when selecting data from MySql?

This is working:

```
<?php
$page = '1001';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `page` = $page LIMIT 1001");
?>
```

but not if $page = 'page_one'.. The row 'page' is VARCHAR (30)

EDIT - trying to clarify question: 
This is what i would like to do, but its not working - gives an error:

```
$page = 'page_one';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `page` = $page LIMIT page_one");
```

Comment: Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Comment: Instead of '1001' i would like to use 'page_one'- letters instead of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add ' around your parameter when its a string and not an integer:

```
$page = "somerandomtext";
SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `page` = '$page' LIMIT 1001
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really use prepared statements:

```
$page = 'abcd';
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `page` = ? LIMIT 1001"));
$stmt->bind_param("s", $page);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: +1, I don't see why this has been downvoted. This is good practise security-wise and solves the problem in the question.

Comment: @MarvinLabs I misunderstood the question and wrote a wrong answer - a fair downvote.  I then corrected the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What he meant was:

```
<?php
$page = '1001';
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `comment` WHERE `page` = '$page' LIMIT 1001");
?>
```

That way the Query String will contain the ' characters..

Comment: If i change '1001' with 'page_one' in both $page and after LIMIT that will not work -

Comment: You cant limit after a string. limit only tells you how many rows to maximum return from the query. Limit 1001 means that 1001 rows can be returned